# waypoints in google maps api shows error

Tags: jquery, api, maps

I am using google maps snap to road api while I am calling waypoints it shows error
**InvalidValueError: in property waypoints: at index 0: unknown property lat**
**TypeError: a is null**

if waypoint is not used I am getting the path but waypoints are not included.

Any help would be helpful.

```
function getPoly() {
        for (var i = 0; i < polyValuesChecked.length; i++) {
            var setLat = parseFloat(polyValuesChecked[i].lat);
            var setLng = parseFloat(polyValuesChecked[i].lng);
        }
        var polys = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            strokeColor: "red",
            zoom: 4
        });

        // BEGIN: Snap to road
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService(), polys, snap_path = [];

        myCoord = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.961608, 77.562039),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.961574, 77.560976),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.961404, 77.559956),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.966734, 77.546926),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.972937, 77.538833),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.985802, 77.525771),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.985565, 77.525554),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.985375, 77.525033),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.985301, 77.524740),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.982437, 77.530903),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.985181, 77.524365),
            new google.maps.LatLng(12.985057, 77.524059)
        ];

        var start = myCoord[0];
        var end = myCoord[myCoord.length - 1];
        myCoord.shift();
        myCoord.pop();

        service.route({
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: myCoord,
            optimizeWaypoints: false,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                console.log("success");
                snap_path = snap_path.concat(result.routes[0].overview_path);
                polys.setPath(snap_path);
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < myCoord.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCoord[i],
                map: map
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints

Your waypoints array should be an array of objects, like so :

```
myCoords = [
    { location : new google.maps.LatLng(12.961608, 77.562039) },
    etc...
]
```